# How to get the return value from an Async Task ActionResult?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the value from an async Task Controller to another Controller.

I am trying to get the return a value *bool* to be treated in a condicional `if(!resController.Result.Value)`,but the program reads it like and error.

Instead, if I try to treat `if(!resController.Value)`, no error is displayed but the value is always *false*.

**First Controller:**

```
[HttpPost("PutClient")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> PutClientAsync(Guid idClient)
        {
            bool result = true;

            try
            {
                result = await _ContasService.PutClientAsync(idClient);
            }
            catch (ExceptionWithError e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e.Error.UserMessages + Environment.NewLine + e.Error.ExceptionMessage);
                return Conflict(e.Error);
            }
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

In the **Second Controller**:

```
resController = await CuttsController.PutCUTAsync(rowContratos);
if (!resController.Result.Value)
    throw new ExceptionWithError(new Error("409", "Error en el PutCUTAsync"));
```

Comment: Just return `result`?

Comment: When I debug I can see the rute of the ``resController.Result.Value`` and It has the boolean value that I want but It can't be called into the program.

Comment: Instead of calling controller method why don't you call `_ContasService.PutClientAsync(rowContratos);` directly?